# How to have different status bar color in flutter for dark and light mode with safe area?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my `Scaffold` in `Safe Area` widget and I want to apply status bar theming but I guess `Safe Area` isn't allowing to do so.

HomePage:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                ? const AssetImage('assets/images/lgt_bg.png')
                : const AssetImage('assets/images/drk_bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              "MnbPub",
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Theme file:

```
class LightTheme {
  static final apptheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 222, 225),
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 222, 225),
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
...
```

#### Also I want the change to happen globally and not only for `home page`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a custom widget called the `ThemedStatusBar` that automatically ensures your status bar is the proper color based on the app's theme. Simply wrap your `Scaffold` with it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ThemedStatusBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThemedStatusBar({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
          ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
          : SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Your order of widgets should be `ThemedStatusBar` -> `Scaffold` -> then somewhere lower (not necessarily directly) a `SafeArea` -> <THE_REST_OF_YOUR_WIDGETS>

Comment: @MNBWorld if this answer helped, please check it as correct to help future users :)

Comment: it still isn't working for m, but i am trying lets see :\

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, but `safe area` comes directly after `themestatusbar` or else few things don't work properly.

Comment: @Matthew_Trent do I need to add this to every page i create? Coz i dont think it will take changes globally

Comment: @MNB Yes, the `ThemedStatusBar` should be added above every `Scaffold` you want to theme automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `SafeArea` around the `Container` in the body parameter.

The `SafeArea` will always clip your app bar & status bar theme if it is around the entire `Scaffold`.